# Is this a known operator decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, svd, tensor-decomposition

Consider a Hermitian operator $H_\mathcal{AB}$ acting on the Hilbert space $
\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$. What is the smallest *commuting* set of  separable operators in the form $A_k\otimes B_k$, such that
$$
H_\mathcal{AB}=\sum_k A_k\otimes B_k?
$$
As pointed out in the comments, a set like this might not even exist.

It would also be interesting to constrain $A_k$ and $B_k$ to be Hermitian themselves. Note that if we didn't require commutativity, we could use the operator singular value decomposition.

Comment: In fact, I'm not convinced that it's necessarily possible to do this with **any** number of commuting operators of that form.

Comment: What is a separable operator ?

Comment: @AndréS. In this context $O$ is separable if it can be written $O=A\otimes B$, with $A$ and $B$ acting on $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, are there explicit examples of operators that cannot be decomposed using a commuting set?

Comment: @Ziofil I don't know whether the statement is true, let alone whether there are explicit examples.